# Convert Concate Text String to Date

Tags: string, postgresql, date

For some reason, the database I am working in as the date saved as a text string of 'YYMMDDHHMM'. We currently have two shifts, with the day shift from 5:00AM - 4:59PM (1659) and the night shift from 5:00PM (1700) to 4:59 AM. I am looking to track productivity each shift per day based on the scans with the above text string.

I am easily able to split these scans into whose shift they belong to using a case:

```
case when right(bch.datetime,4) <= 0459 then 'Night'
when right(bch.datetime,4) >= 1700 then 'Night'
when right(bch.datetime,4) between 0500 and 1659 then 'Day'
else '???' end as Shift
```

The problem is the Night shifts are incorrectly being split into the two days when I went to have them grouped together as one.

For example, if I am pulling the Night Shift scans for the week of Monday March 15th - Friday March 19th, the times they would have worked in the system are:

- 2103151700 - 2103169459
- 2103161700 - 2103179459
- 2103171700 - 2103189459
- 2103181700 - 2103199459
- 2103191700 - 2103209459

So if I just go by these dates, I end up with half day scans on the 15th, instead of seeing their fully productivity in the evening of the 15th and the morning of the 16th. Similar, if I look at everything scanned on the 16th, I really get the second half of one of their shifts and the first half of their other shift. Ideally, I could use another case here to just go back a date when the scan time is between 0000 and 0459, but with how the date is formatted as a text string, I can't do that.

Trying to use: `to_date(concat(20, left(b.datetime,6)), 'YYYYMMDD')` have  failed with an error of "Invalid user-defined or scalar function". Different versions of this had all resulted in the same error.  Just need to get this into a valid date format. Any thoughts on how I can make this work all with a PSQL Script instead of having to export the raw data into excel and manipulate from there?

Thank you!

Edit: I got the following error when trying to use `to_timestamp(bch.datetime, 'YYMMDDHH24MI')` :

```
[LNA][PSQL][SQL Engine]Error in expression: to_timestamp ( bch . datetime, 'YYMMDDHH24MI' ) 
[LNA][PSQL][SQL Engine][Data Record Manager]Invalid user-defined or scalar function.
```

Edit 2: The version of PSQL I am using is 12.10.067. Trying to get the simple query done first between using cases to get the shift that overlaps two date to reflect as just the former by doing a case for date around if the time occurs between midnight and 05:59, then count it as the previous date. But I need to get the date in a date format first to have it take the previous date, so that is my struggle. But even with the simple query I am getting the above error. It works without to to_timestamp, but not with. The base query I am using is:

````
bch.so_line_no,
bch.lite_no,
bch.department,
bch.piece_no,
bch.datetime,
to_timestamp(bch.datetime, 'YYMMDDHH24MI')

from batch_scan_hist as bch

where left(bch.datetime,6) between '210328' and '210403'

order by bch.datetime```
````

Comment: `to_timestamp(b.datetime, 'YYMMDDHH24MI')` should get you a valid timestamp

Comment: Thank you, but didn't work. I got the following error: `[LNA][PSQL][SQL Engine]Error in expression: to_timestamp ( bch . datetime, 'YYMMDDHH24MI' ) 
[LNA][PSQL][SQL Engine][Data Record Manager]Invalid user-defined or scalar function.`

Comment: That's pretty weird. What version of postgres are you using? And can you include the full query you used when you got that "invalid user-defined or scalar function" error?

Comment: The PSQL version is 12.10.067. The query is fairly simple, as I am just trying to get the date aspect to work first before adding any other aspects to the query. It works fine without the to_timestamp, but with the to_timestamp I get the error.: 
```select bch.so_no,
bch.so_line_no,
bch.lite_no,
bch.department,
bch.piece_no,
bch.datetime,
to_timestamp(bch.datetime, 'YYMMDDHH24MI')

from batch_scan_hist as bch

where left(bch.datetime,6) between '210328' and '210403'

order by bch.datetime```

Comment: Is it possible you're using Actian Pervasive SQL and not PostgreSQL? Both can be abbreviated to PSQL, but they're very different products. Your error kind of looks like a Pervasive SQL error to me. If that's the case, you can close this question and ask again with the correct tags.